# Search and Highlight arabic characters text in UIWebView using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, uiwebview

I am using JavaScript to highlight the occurrence of characters in a `UIWebView`. I use the following JavaScript code:

```
var uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;

function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element,keyword) {

    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 3) {        // Text node
            while (true) {
                //if (counter < 1) {
                var value = element.nodeValue;  // Search for keyword in text node
                var idx = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);

                if (idx < 0) break;             // not found, abort

                //(value.split);

                //we create a SPAN element for every parts of matched keywords
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                var text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx,keyword.length));
                span.appendChild(text);

                span.setAttribute("class","uiWebviewHighlight");
                span.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
                span.style.color="black";

                uiWebview_SearchResultCount++;    // update the counter

                text = document.createTextNode(value.substr(idx+keyword.length));
                element.deleteData(idx, value.length - idx);
                var next = element.nextSibling;
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(span, next);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text, next);
                element = text;
                window.scrollTo(0,span.offsetTop);

            }
        } else if (element.nodeType == 1) { // Element node
            if (element.style.display != "none" && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'select') {
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(element.childNodes[i],keyword);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// the main entry point to start the search
function uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString(keyword) {

    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights();
    uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfStringForElement(document.body, keyword.toLowerCase());
}

// helper function, recursively removes the highlights in elements and their childs
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.nodeType == 1) {
            if (element.getAttribute("class") == "uiWebviewHighlight") {
                var text = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(text,element);
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                return true;
            } else {
                var normalize = false;
                for (var i=element.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if (uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(element.childNodes[i])) {
                        normalize = true;
                    }
                }
                if (normalize) {
                    element.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// the main entry point to remove the highlights
function uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights() {
    uiWebview_SearchResultCount = 0;
    uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlightsForElement(document.body);
}
```

I then call this and everything works fine. My problem is that for characters that are in the middle of a word (for example و which is in the middle of توحید), it disconnects the و character from its previous character (and it becomes ت وحید).

Comment: This might not be your problem, but remember, arabic goes from right to left (0 index is at the right end, not the left). This is how the browser writes it and how you should iterate through it. I would make sure that your code first works with english. If it does, then for arabic, just reverse your iteration.

Comment: @J148 It actually works fine with english, and works fine with arabic too. Meaning that it highlightens all the occurrences of the given characters. The only problem is that it disconnects the characters from its previous characters as i explained above.